# xxxx does not name a type C++

Tags: c++, class, gcc

I'm a newbie on C/C++ and trying to improve coding skills. I am writing a minimal code to calculates a formula used in my college studies. This code consists of a number of classes. While I'm trying to build it, I'm getting error said in title for a class. Here's my code:

materials.hpp

```
#ifndef MATERIALS_HPP
#define MATERIALS_HPP

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class materials{
public: 
double MassNumber, AtomNumber, Density, I, C, a, m, X1, X0, X, delta; 

    materials();
    materials(double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double);
     ~materials();
};

materials Magnesium;
materials Cupper;
materials Alluminium;
materials Plumbo;
materials Water;

#endif // MATERIALS_HPP
```

And this is the source;

materials.cpp

```
#include "materials.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

materials::materials()
{
    MassNumber = AtomNumber = Density = I = a = m = C = X1 = X0 = X = delta = 0.0;
}

materials::materials(double a1, double a2, double a3, double a4, double a5, double a6,double a7, double a8, double a9)
{
    MassNumber = a1;
    AtomNumber = a2;
    Density = a3;
    I = a4;
    C = a5;
    a = a6;
    m = a7;
    X1 = a8;
    X0 = a9;
}

Magnesium.materials(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499);
Cupper.materials(63.0, 29.0, 8.96, 322.0, -4.42, 0.1434, 2.90, 3.28, 0.0254);
Alluminium.materials(26.0, 13.0, 2.70, 166.0, -4.24, 0.0802, 3.63, 3.01, 0.1708);
Plumbo.materials(207.0, 82.0, 11.34, 823.0, -6.20, 0.0936, 3.16, 3.81, 0.3776);
Water.materials(18.0, 10.0, 1.0, 75.0, -3.50, 0.0911, 3.48, 2.80, 0.2400);
```

And errors I'm getting;

```
materials.cpp:64:1: error: 'Magnesium' does not name a type
 Magnesium.materials(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499
);
 ^
materials.cpp:66:1: error: 'Cupper' does not name a type
Cupper.materials(63.0, 29.0, 8.96, 322.0, -4.42, 0.1434, 2.90, 3.28, 0.0254);
^
materials.cpp:68:1: error: 'Alluminium' does not name a type
Alluminium.materials(26.0, 13.0, 2.70, 166.0, -4.24, 0.0802, 3.63, 3.01, 0.1708
);
^
materials.cpp:70:1: error: 'Plumbo' does not name a type
Plumbo.materials(207.0, 82.0, 11.34, 823.0, -6.20, 0.0936, 3.16, 3.81, 0.3776);

^
materials.cpp:72:1: error: 'Water' does not name a type
Water.materials(18.0, 10.0, 1.0, 75.0, -3.50, 0.0911, 3.48, 2.80, 0.2400);
^
make: *** [materials.o] Error 1
```

I'm trying it on GCC 4.9.0 on Linux and MinGW with GCC 4.8.1 on Windows. I'v read other articles about it but I couldn't make it. Why do I get this errors?

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot any class declaration for `Magnesium`, etc. in your code? Just a bunch of (wrong) global variable definitions. Did you mean to make a typedef or inherit?

Comment: It's a very bad idea to instantiate those global variables in the header file (unless you're not planning to include this file anywhere else). Declare them `extern` in the header file, and instantiate them in the source file. Header files should typically contain only compiler "hints" (i.e., declarations), while global variables are an actual part of the executable image.

Comment: I prefer small examples which I can compile in a few seconds. You gave us hundrets of lines here to show one error message. Please shrink your examples so that it is easier for all readers to catch the problem!

Comment: This would be a good sample how to do such with a simple straightforward `template<trait params> class Material;` and a bunch of typedefs for all the concrete `Material` instantiations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want these global variables to be accessible in other source files:

**Change to this in the header file:**

```
extern materials Magnesium;
extern materials Cupper;
extern materials Alluminium;
extern materials Plumbo;
extern materials Water;
```

**Change to this in the source file:**

```
materials Magnesium(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499);
materials Cupper(63.0, 29.0, 8.96, 322.0, -4.42, 0.1434, 2.90, 3.28, 0.0254);
materials Alluminium(26.0, 13.0, 2.70, 166.0, -4.24, 0.0802, 3.63, 3.01, 0.1708);
materials Plumbo(207.0, 82.0, 11.34, 823.0, -6.20, 0.0936, 3.16, 3.81, 0.3776);
materials Water(18.0, 10.0, 1.0, 75.0, -3.50, 0.0911, 3.48, 2.80, 0.2400);
```

---

If you do not want these global variables to be accessible in other source files:

**Remove this from the header file:**

```
materials Magnesium;
materials Cupper;
materials Alluminium;
materials Plumbo;
materials Water;
```

**Change to this in the source file:**

```
static materials Magnesium(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499);
static materials Cupper(63.0, 29.0, 8.96, 322.0, -4.42, 0.1434, 2.90, 3.28, 0.0254);
static materials Alluminium(26.0, 13.0, 2.70, 166.0, -4.24, 0.0802, 3.63, 3.01, 0.1708);
static materials Plumbo(207.0, 82.0, 11.34, 823.0, -6.20, 0.0936, 3.16, 3.81, 0.3776);
static materials Water(18.0, 10.0, 1.0, 75.0, -3.50, 0.0911, 3.48, 2.80, 0.2400);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably go hunt down a good introduction on how classes in C++ work.

The problem is, you're trying to do some sort of strange two part construction, by first declaring

```
materials Magnesium;
```

and then trying to explicitly invoke

```
Magnesium.materials(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499);
```

but constructors do not work like that in C++!

You should be doing this instead:

```
materials Magnesium(23.0, 12.0, 1.738, 156.0, -4.53, 0.0816, 3.62, 3.07, 0.1499);
```

This isn't really the place to explain the details of class construction, but I can safely say that you should do some more research into this.

Comment: Sorry. English isn't my native language and despite this fact, I want to do something on my own. I have too much thing to learn exactly, but it was just beginning for me. Thank you for your help.